# PHP make hyperlink from text by regex match

Tags: php, function, loops, hyperlink

I have a script that make links (http, https and www) in a sentence clickable. The problem is that I can only have one link. Can I resolve this with a loop within the if statement of any kind?

```
$text = "Both www.google.com and http://www.google.com/calendar/ are links";

/**
* Make clickable links from URLs in text.
*/
function make_clickable($text) {

  // Force http to www.
  $text = preg_replace( "(www\.)", "http://www.", $text );

  // Delete duplicates after force.
  $text = preg_replace( "(http://http://www\.)", "http://www.", $text );
  $text = preg_replace( "(https://http://www\.)", "https://www.", $text );

  // The RegEx.
  $regExUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

  // Check if there is a URL in the text.
  if(preg_match($regExUrl, $text, $url)) {

    // Make the URLs hyper links.
    $text = preg_replace(
      $regExUrl,
      '<a href="' . $url[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $url[0] . '</a>',
      $text
    );

  }    

  return $text;

}

echo make_clickable($text);
```

**Result:**
Both http://www.google.com and http://www.google.com are links

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? This seems to be working as expected...

Comment: Nope, look at the input links in the variable. The output just gives me the first link for both (two times). If the input is http://stackoverflow.com/ and http://google.com I will get http://stackoverflow.com/ two times. Therefor I might need a loop, I think. Do you get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any loop. Try this:

```
/**
* Make clickable links from URLs in text.
*/

    function make_clickable($text) {

      // Force http to www.
      $text = preg_replace( "(www\.)", "http://www.", $text );

      // Delete duplicates after force.
      $text = preg_replace( "(http://http://www\.)", "http://www.", $text );
      $text = preg_replace( "(https://http://www\.)", "https://www.", $text );

      // The RegEx.
      $regExUrl = "/(http|https)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

      // Check if there are URLs in the text then replace all
      $text = preg_replace_callback($regExUrl, function($matches) {
            return '<a href="' . $matches[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $matches[0] . '</a>';
      }, $text);

      return $text;
    }
```

Ref: [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)